# Showing content of div based on previous input option choice (radio button). Working in one file, not in other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radio-button

I have a two step form. The first step asks a question and has 3 radio buttons.

Based on which radio button is selected, the second step shows the answer by 'unhiding' a div.

For e.g. **Step 1:**
What option do you select?
Option 1,
Option 2,
Option 3

**Step 2:**
Has 3 hidden divs, based on the option in step 1, one of them is changed from display:none, to display:block and is shown.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("input[rel$='lastq']").click(function () {
var value = $(this).val();
if (value == 'last1') {
$(".thank1").show();
$(".thank2").hide();
$(".thank3").hide();
}               
else if (value == 'last2') {
$(".thank2").show();
$(".thank1").hide();
$(".thank3").hide();
} 
else if (value == 'last3') {
$(".thank3").show();
$(".thank1").hide();
$(".thank2").hide();
}
else {
$(".thank1").hide();
$(".thank2").hide();
$(".thank3").hide();
}
});
$(".thank1").hide();
$(".thank2").hide();
$(".thank3").hide();
});
```

And my html is:

```
<input type="radio" rel="lastq" name="" value="last1" id="" /> Option 1
<input type="radio" rel="lastq" name="" value="last2" id="" /> Option 2
<input type="radio" rel="lastq" name="" value="last3" id="" /> Option 3

<div class="thank1">thank you 1</div>
<div class="thank2">thank you 2</div>
<div class="thank3">thank you 3</div>
```

Now the weird thing is this is working fine with a single file (locally), the correct 'thank you' div shows. But when I use it (locally again) in one my project (using wordpress on local machine), it does not work.

**Observed problem:**

1) When it works, the "thank you divs" are by default style="display:none;"

2) But when used in the project, when not working, the thank you divs do not have the display:none assigned to them.

What could be causing this? Why isn't it getting assigned in the project, but still working in the standalone file?

Comment: It sounds like possibly jQuery is not being imported in your wordpress template. Do you have any errors in the javascript console?

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED by adding $ = jquery.noconflict() at the top of the script code.

The jquery was loading fine, but it must be conflicting with some other script maybe?

Anyway, issue solved for anyone coming here later...